# Labelled Generic containing `$eq`

Tags: mongodb, scala, shapeless

Shapeless 2.3.3 `LabelledGeneric` returns a curious result when run on the following case class:

```
scala> case class Foo(`$eq`: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> LabelledGeneric[Foo]
res0: shapeless.LabelledGeneric[Foo]{type Repr = Int with shapeless.labelled.KeyTag[Symbol with shapeless.tag.Tagged[String("=")],Int] :: shapeless.HNil} = shapeless.LabelledGeneric$$anon$1@1ac7dbd3
```

Note the label returned is literally `=` instead of `$eq`.

Is this behaviour a quirk of shapeless or something else? Are there other identifier names that result in weird behaviour?

I require this for MongoDB serialization and this kind of a major headache for me ...

Comment: Can you use a different field name?

Comment: It's more of a quirk of Scala: identifiers containing operator symbols have to be translated to legal JVM identifiers which can't contain them, see "Operators are Methods" in http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala for a complete list. So if you had `=` as a field name somehow, it would become `$eq` in the bytecode. Apparently Shapeless assumes that's what happened and translates back, which would be the desired behavior in most cases.

Comment: Alexey thanks that seems absolutely correct. I wish you would have added it as an answer so I could credit you. I will write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Alexey's comment in the Q, this is a 'feature' in Shapeless, because of the way scala/java interop works. The latter is explained in [Daniel Spiewak's blot post](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala) under "operators and overaloading".

The list of operators, per the blog, that this affects are:

```
op  Compiles To
=   $eq
>   $greater
<   $less
+   $plus
-   $minus
*   $times
/   div
!   $bang
@   $at
#   $hash
%   $percent
^   $up
&   $amp
~   $tilde
?   $qmark
|   $bar
\   $bslash
:   $colon
```